# Can emulators show an Android app's details page?

Tags: android, emulation

I have code straight from Google's dev guide:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It works perfectly on a physical device, the app crashes on Android emulators.  Are Android emulators capable of doing it?

Comment: put logcat if app crashes ...and if you have error always put your full logcat in question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Here is what in logcat: 03-15 08:05:47.637: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=mypackage }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Play Store (formerly known as the Android Market) does not exist on emulators.

Comment: I never expected this would be the answer - Google's Android emulators do not support Google's Android Market.  Thank you for the prompt response.